# history.transitionTo is not a function, created by history/createBrowserHistory

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

Try to create application with redux, immutable and react-redux-router.

Versions of used packages:

```
"immutable": "^3.8.2",
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-immutable": "^4.0.0"
```

I'm creating a history with `createSagaMiddleware` function from [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) npm package.

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const browserHistory: any = createHistory();
```

But if I pass this instance of the History to the `syncHistoryWithStore` function for syncing my location and state from store

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
    selectLocationState: createSelectLocationState()
});
```

I get following error when I try to navigate to some page:

[image]

Because my history object hasn't got a `transitionTo` function.

Where can I get the History object that is suitable for this task?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should change version of react-router-redux, because "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8" works only with react-router v3, but you use react-router v4(react-router-dom)

```
npm i react-router-redux@next --save-dev
```